# Atom feeds in Chat Search do not work when query contains a colon

Tags: bug, chat, feed

To reproduce click

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag%3Aphp

This will give the chat transcripts for `tag:php`. Scroll down and click the Feed icon

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/feeds/search/tag%3aphp

This will produce

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/feeds/search/tag:php

Comment: it does work w/o the colon.

Comment: @hakre it does, but produces different results

Comment: Yes I ran over the same thing last week. It does not work as well with the `[]` characters IIRC.